# include processed prepocessor directives into `g++ -E' output

Tags: g++, c-preprocessor

I'm having some preprocessing mishap while compiling a 3rd party library with `g++`.

I can see in `-E` output that a certain header wrapped with `#ifndef SYMBOL` is being bypassed. Apparently, that symbol has been defined somewhere else.
But I cannot see where because processed directives are not present in the `-E` output.

Is there a way to include them (as comments, probably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I found is the [`-d<chars>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) family of options:

- `-dM` dumps all the macros that are defined
- `-dD` shows where they are defined (dumps `#define` directives)
- `-dU` shows where they are used (in place of `#if(n)def`, it outputs `#define` or `#undef` depending on whether the macro was defined)

  Adding `I` to any of these also dumps `#include` directives.

The downside is only one of the three can be used at a time and they suppress normal output.

Another, less understandable downside is `-dD` and `-dU` do not include predefined macros.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard way to get preprocessed directives as comments.

However, you could use `g++ -C -E` and the line numbers (output in lines starting with `#`) and the comments (which are then copied to the preprocessed form).

And you might also use the `-H` option (to get the included files)